# Delete oldest file for each directory in a tree

Tags: linux, find

I have a directory tree like the following:

```
Games
-- Game1
  -- file1
  -- file2
  -- file3
-- Game2
  -- file1
  -- file2
-- GameN
  -- filen
```

And I would like to delete the oldest file for each Game subdirectory.

Tried searching for the various questions already posted but didn't find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files not containing special characters, like `\n` (no problem with files with spaces):

```
for dir in Games/Game*/; do
    (
        cd "$dir"
        echo rm "$(\ls -tr | sed q)"
    )
done
```

This is the only one case where I parse `ls`

Drop `echo` command if your attempts are satisfactory.

- `ls -tr` sort files by date of modification in reverse order.
- `sed q` take the first line